# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'children') using context in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use context. but I'm having that error
Put my 2 files below

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Consumer, useContext } from 'react'
//import MessageContract from '../build/Message.json'
import WalletProvider  from '../context/WalletContext'

function App() {

  const { 
    web3Provider, 
    address, 
    isConnected, 
    chainId, 
    networkId, 
    errorMsg, 
    connectWallet
  } = useContext(WalletProvider)

  return (

    <WalletProvider>
      <div className="App">
        <button className="button is-primary" onClick={connectWallet}>
          {address && address.length > 0
                    ? `Connected: ${address.substring(
                        0,
                        6
                      )}...${address.substring(38)}`
                    : "Connect Wallet"}       
        </button>
      </div>
    </WalletProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And the context file

```
    import React, {useState, useEffect, createContext} from 'react';
import Web3 from 'web3';

const WalletContext = createContext("")

export const WalletProvider = ({props}) => {

    const [web3Provider, setWeb3Provider] = useState(null)
    const [address, setAddress] = useState(null)
    const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(false)
    const [chainId, setChainId] = useState('')
    const [networkId, setNetworkId] = useState('')
    const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState('')

    const connectWallet = async () => {

        if( !isConnected) {
          try {
            // connect web3
            let web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
            setWeb3Provider(web3)
            // get acounts
            const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
            setAddress(accounts[0])
    
            if ( accounts ) {
              let networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId()
              setNetworkId(networkId)
              let chainId = await web3.eth.getChainId()
              setChainId(chainId)
            }
    
          } catch (error) {
            setErrorMsg(error)
          }
          setIsConnected(true)
        }
      } 

    return  (
        <WalletContext.Provider value= {{
            web3Provider,
            address,
            isConnected,
            chainId,
            networkId,
            errorMsg,
            connectWallet
        }}>
            {props.children}
        </WalletContext.Provider>
    )
}
export default WalletContext;
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Change to `export const WalletProvider = (props) => { ...`. You're destructuring the props.

Comment: ok, that solved this problem, but now i'm getting another... will try and come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is incorrect

```
const {...} = useContext(WalletProvider)
```

`useContext` takes the *context* as an argument, not the provider.